# Selecting data from database in a foreach loop is always 7

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am making this for adding storage in an admin section of my site. I have encountered a very strange problem. $voorraad always equals 7, no matter what product I choose(id changes), it keeps coming up as 7.

I am echoing $voorraad by making a session and echoing it in an other page.
The table name and column is correct. Can someone explain why $voorraad always equals seven?
If you need more code, I will provide it.

```
 $cartItems = $cart->contents();
        foreach($cartItems as $item){
            $sql = ("SELECT voorraad FROM Producten WHERE id =".$item['id']);
            $voorraad = (float)mysql_query($sql);
            $itm = (float)$item['qty'];
            $_SESSION['voorraad'] = $voorraad;
            $_SESSION['itm'] = $itm;               
            $up = $itm + $voorraad;
            $sql1 = "UPDATE Producten SET voorraad = $up WHERE id =".$item['id'];
            $res = mysql_query($sql1);

        }
```

Comment: Not sure how you're getting your variables, but make sure the user isn't providing them, because then you're open to SQL injection. Also mysql_* are deprecated, switch to mysqli_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are converting the mysql response object into a float, you're not actually getting the result.

```
$voorraad = mysql_query($sql);
$voorraad = mysql_fetch_assoc($voorraad)['voorraad']; // get the row, and the cell from the row
```

`$voorraad` should now contain the actual response.

Comment: Wow thanks! I absolutely did not know it was that simple. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You are wide open to **SQL injection**. Filter and validate your user input before passing it to the query.

Second thing: Don't use `mysql_*`, it's deprecated and considered not safe anymore. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

`mysql_query()` returns a `resource`, which you try to cast to `float`. To access the Value(s) you have to use

```
$result = mysql_query(....);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$voorraad = $row['voorraad'];
```

Comment: Making this in school, no protection needed. Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0):

First of all - `mysql_*`-functions are deprecated and if you update your php version, you couldn't use them anymore. Second, you should use prepared statements, to prevent sql injections.

Back to your main problem:
You execute the query, but you never fetch the result, so you just cast a `resource` return type to an float, which gives you your unexpected result. In your case, you could use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get the row, you want

Because you are converting the mysql response object into a float, you're not actually getting the result.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$column = $row['column_name'];
```